# Textarea Sideways Scrolling Cancellation

Tags: html, textarea

This is kind of hard to explain, but here is my problem:
When, at least on my laptop, you scroll upwards with the touch-pad, the cursor won't move.  If you scroll sideways, the cursor moves sideways.  I'd rather the cursor doesn't move at all.  Is this possible?  Can you cancel side-ways scrolling?  Can you enable upwards scrolling?

Thanks, hopefully that is comprehensible.

Comment: This sounds very much like a hardware or browser related issue. If not, post us an example of the problem and how to recreate it.

Comment: I'll post an example as soon as possible

Comment: ok, well, all you need to do is just create a `<textarea>`, type something in it, and scroll sideways.  I tried it on chrome, internet explorer, and firefox, and the problem persisted.  If I must, here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/mretchin/z9Nmk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your problem, you want to control the scroll of your textarea! So, in order to control the scroll of a textarea, you can use CSS just like you use it to any other element that as scrolling capabilities:

**No scroll**

```
<style type="text/css">
  textarea {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
</style>
```

**No vertical scroll**

```
<style type="text/css">
  textarea {
    overflow-y: hidden;
  }
</style>
```

**No horizontal scroll**

```
<style type="text/css">
  textarea {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
</style>
```

Additionally, you can disable the text wrapping, thus forcing an horizontal scroll bar (non-W3c-compliant).

**Textarea tag to disable wrap**

```
<textarea cols="60" rows="12" wrap="off">My long text string is this big and continues...</textarea>
```

Note: Just tested this on your Fiddle.

Comment: sorry, nope.  I mean, if you use the touchpad on your laptop, and scroll left or right, the cursor moves.  I don't mean overflow

Comment: Your cursor moves and not the scroll bar ?? Is that whats happening? I'm confused...

Comment: regardless of whether there is a scroll bar or not, I checked on both, the cursor moves when you scroll sideways.

Comment: And that's what happens on all browsers that you have to test on?

Comment: yes, but I haven't checked opera, I'll try on that, I could try on a different laptop to check if it's a hardware issue, I'll come back and comment once I've done that

Comment: Well, if it happens on every browser, that's most definitely an hardware/configuration issue, since it doesn't happen with my laptop :)

Comment: it works on my brother's laptop, and he's on a samsung- I'm on an asus

Comment: if most end-users won't have this problem, I don't think I'll worry about it @Zuul

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10654/discussion-between-zuul-and-matt)